# Layout break in IE11 but in Chrome works fine

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I have this archive in my site and works fine. But when I open it in IE11 the image is not resized.

in Chrome:
[image: 1]

in IE11:
[image]

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#img">Img 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#imgg">Img 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#imge">Img 3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#imgee">Img 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="img" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <img src='img1.png' width="90%" />
    </div>
    <div id="imgg" class="tab-pane fade">
      <img src='img2.png' width="90%" />
    </div>
    <div id="imge" class="tab-pane fade">
      <img src='img3.png' width="90%" />
    </div>
    <div id="imgee" class="tab-pane fade">
      <img src='img4.png' width="90%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .tab-pane {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Someone know why the img breaks in IE11?

Comment: Microsoft now describe IE11 as a legacy product rather than a browser!

Comment: Oh. I dont know that, thank you for help and Im sorry but why this is relevant in my case? Im new in web developer

Comment: It could mean that you're developing for a legacy product that is no longer supported. It would be suggested that you try and develop for newer browsers such as Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

Comment: why do we still dig IE out of the graveyard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample using your code, it seems that everything works well in IE browser, the screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8Xc.gif). Please check your code, whether there have any other CSS style?

Besides,try to clear the browser data (such as:cache), and then you could try to use F12 developer tools to check the HTML elements and CSS style. Then, try to set the div container width property. such as:

```
<style>
    .tab-pane {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .container{
        width:90%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE11 screen width isn't [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_screen_width).

You can use css rules in order to achieve that like so:

```
.tab-pane img{
  width: 90%;
```

}

Don't forget to remove the inline property from your img tags.

Comment: Hi @Eytan thank you for help. But nothing change with this configurations. The layout keep with the same problem